# Form input fields don't have the same spacing

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, spacing

I am absolutely confused by the following. In mine website I included a simple registration form with 5 input fields (types text, input and email). Though for some reason the 5 input fields all have different spacing, at least the input types email and password have the same spacing but the type text has a different one (see image).

So the first thing what you think is: change all the fields to the same type, like the type text. So I did but still I am having the same problem. Second thing what I thought was, reset all the (browser) css/styling. So I included a style reset but this also didn’t have any effect. So now I am stuck on this issue. I tried to fix it by giving each input field a different class with different top-margins so they would have (nearly - based on my view) the same spacing. The problem with this solution is that I also have an error message (like submitted email is incorrect) when the form is incorrect (which is a pop-up based on the labels) though, the error messages are connected to the labels (programmed in the jQuery), so this results in a wrong position of the error messages (they aren’t exactly behind the input field) - see image.

The image link of the problem (since I can’t upload pictures yet): http://s18.postimg.org/f8ct2f789/Problem1.png

The HTML is as follows:

```
<body>  
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo_wrapper">
                <span class="logonaam1">O</span><span class="logonaam2">b</span><span class="logonaam1">l</span><span class="logonaam2">e</span><span class="logonaam1">c</span><span class="logonaam2">t</span><span class="logonaam1">a</span><span class="logonaam2">r</span><span class="logonaam1">e</span>
            </div>
                <form action="login.php" method="post">
                    <div id="aanmeldform_submit">
                        <input type="submit" name = "submit_login" value="Aanmelden" id="submit_knop" />
                    </div>

                    <div id="aanmeldform_wachtwoord">
                        <input type="password" name ="password" value="" id="aanmeld_knop" required placeholder="Voer je wachtwoord in" />   
                    </div>

                    <div id="aanmeldform_email">
                        <input type="email" name="email" value="" id="aanmeld_knop" required placeholder="Voer je e-mail in" autofocus/>   
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>






        <div id="register_wrapper">
            <div class="Regi">Registreren</div>
                    <form class="registratie_form" id = "register-form" action="register.php" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" >                   
                    
                    
                    <div class="fieldContainer">
                        <label for="voornaam"></label> 
                            <input type="text" name="voornaam" id="voornaam" class="allInputs" required placeholder="Jouw voornaam" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,}">                                 
                    </div>

                    <div class="fieldContainer">  
                        <label for="achternaam"></label>       
                            <input type="text" name="achternaam" id="achternaam" class="allInputs" required placeholder="Jouw achternaam" pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,}">                              
                    </div>

                    <div class="fieldContainer">
                        <label for="email"></label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="allInputs" required placeholder="Jouw e-mail adres" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="fieldContainer">
                        <label for="emailvalidation"></label>
                            <input type="text" name="emailvalidation" id="emailvalidation" class="allInputs" required placeholder="Bevestig jouw e-mail adres" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="fieldContainer">    
                        <label for="wachtwoord"></label>    
                            <input type="text" name="wachtwoord" id="wachtwoord" class="allInputs" required placeholder="Voer jouw wachtwoord in" pattern=".{4,}" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="fieldContainer">
                            <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Registreren" id="submit_knop_registreren" >
                    </div>




                </form>


        </div>



    </div>

    <div class="Regi2">Waren jouw vrienden hier bij? Meld je aan en kom er achter!</div>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="image-slider-wrapper">
            <ul id="image_slider">
                <li><img src="/debasis/hoofdstuk03/Icons index/Index pic 1.jpg" width="600px" height="300px"></li>
                <li><img src="/debasis/hoofdstuk03/Icons index/Index pic 2.jpg" width="600px" height="300px"></li>
                <li><img src="/debasis/hoofdstuk03/Icons index/Index pic 3.jpg" width="600px" height="300px"></li>
                <li><img src="/debasis/hoofdstuk03/Icons index/Index pic 4.jpg" width="600px" height="300px"></li>
                <li><img src="/debasis/hoofdstuk03/Icons index/Index pic 5.jpg" width="600px" height="300px"></li>

            </ul>           
            <div class="pager">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

I inserted the rest of my code (jquery, html and css) in this fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/jaaG5
```

you can also see the space problem in this fiddle.

Hope some smart guy in here knows the problem, and better, the solution;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something (probably JQuery itself) is creating a lot of code junk between your inputs. I'm not by any means good with JQuery, but there isn't any line breaks (<br> tags) on your HTML, so i'm assuming it is JQuery's fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed here in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pscott/jaaG5/5/)

The inspector showed

```
&npsb; &nbsp;
```

in several places inside the fieldContainers.

The problem seems to be some extra spacing in your .fieldContainer divs.  Run your HTML through an HTML tidy processor like this [one](http://infohound.net/tidy/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did the trick. Never knew you could also have hidden line breaks... Thx!

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of non breaking spaces inside first 2 input textboxes,
if you do inspect element, then you will be able to see these

After removing those   first 2 textboxes will be aligned same, as of others.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried putting the form input fields in table tr and td tags? Its a nice and neat practice to keep the form tidy and hopefully fix your problem...

Comment: I wouldn't call this an answer, more a comment!

Comment: I played around with 
    .fieldContainer {
    position: relative;
    margin: 5;
    height:25px; You are more familiar with your code, but your CSS is the problem...